# Yodlee FastLink: postMessages doesn't comes from iframe

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to integrate Yodlee fastLink with our app. I successfully opened it in the iframe, but the only postMessage that I'm receiving from Yodlee is "loadModule". I can login, see linked accounts, but after each action I dont receive any message as it described in docs.
I've provided locationurl param in extraParams and created a subscription in my component by addEventListener. Maybe some workaround on it?

I've tried to add extraParams like in https://colinramsay.co.uk/2018/07/25/yodlee-fastlink-postmessage.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it locally as a HTML file? You should host that on a server, it can be localhost as well.